# How to find Cursor position in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Would someone help me in finding cursor position in a JTextArea in terms of pixel?
I have used `txtArea.getCaretPosition()`. But this is not the position I expect. Actually i want the cursor position in `x,y` coordinate of pixel.

Answer (score 4):

[TextUI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TextUI.html) have method `modelToView` that'll give you position/size of the caret:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;


public class PixelPositionOfCaretDemo
{
    public PixelPositionOfCaretDemo()
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Move the caret...");
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        area.addCaretListener(new MyCaretListener(label));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(400, 400, 400, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyCaretListener implements CaretListener
    {
        private final JLabel label;

        MyCaretListener(JLabel label)
        {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e)
        {
            JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
            try
            {
                Rectangle rect = textComp.getUI().modelToView(textComp, e.getDot());
                label.setText(rect.toString());
            }
            catch (BadLocationException ex)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get pixel position of caret", ex);
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new PixelPositionOfCaretDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, You don't need to use the UI for this. You can use textComponent.modelToView(...).

Comment: @camickr: Good point, I'm surprised I missed this when scrolling through API of JTextComponent but found it "deeper" in the TextUI :) I'm thinking: what's "best practice" in cases like this, update my answer according to your comment or keep it as to preserve "history"?

Comment: Good question; two common practices include 1) post a separate answer with the alternate approach, and 2) add a link to the relevant `edit` history section.

Answer (score 2):

Note that some of these answers return the location relative to the text component you're getting the caret position from.

If you want to get the caret's position on the screen, I suggest you use this method:

```
Caret caret = yourTextComponent.getCaret();
Point p = caret.getMagicCaretPosition();
p.x += yourTextComponent.getLocationOnScreen().x;
p.y += yourTextComponent.getLocationOnScreen().y;

aFrameYourePositioning.setLocation(p);
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm. Had problems using any other approach to show a JPopupMenu using these coordinates but this one was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use the FontMetrics class.
Analyze the text, figure out the new lines / wrapping of the text.
then use

```
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10);  
    FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font);
    Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds("string", null);  
    int widthInPixels = (int) bounds.getWidth();
```

etc....

And if you really want, post your solution here to be cool. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like below

```
Point point = textArea.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition();
```

Please be aware the point could be null

Answer (score 0):

I made this one after trying the other posts here. It works perfectly as long has your textarea has text wrapping disabled.

```
public Point getCaretPixelPosition(JTextArea a) {
    try {
        int cpos = a.getCaretPosition();
        Font font = a.getStyledDocument().getFont(a.getStyledDocument().getLogicalStyle(cpos));
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(font);

        int lineNum = a.getLineOfOffset(cpos);
        int y = lineNum * metrics.getHeight();
        int lineStart = a.getLineStartOffset(lineNum);
        int x = metrics.stringWidth(a.getText().substring(lineStart, cpos));

                    return new Point(x,y);

    } catch(BadLocationException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle caretRect=textPane.getUI().modelToView(textPane,textPane.getCaretPosition());
```

or

```
Rectangle caretRect=textPane.modelToView(textPane.getCaretPosition());
```

for example; use this rect for showing popup:

popupMenu.show(textPane, caretRect.x, caretRect.y);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to display a JPopup at the caret position

```
Caret caret = logText.getCaret();
Point p = new Point(caret.getMagicCaretPosition());
p.x += logText.getLocationOnScreen().x;
p.y += logText.getLocationOnScreen().y;

SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, actionsPanel);
popup.show(actionsPanel, p.x, p.y);
```