# Extracting closest sentence from a string

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a very small SQL editor, mostly for novelty.
I'm able to execute all statements now, by just splitting the entire text by semicolons, and running one statement after the other.

However, I wish to implement a feature where I only run the statement closest to the cursor, but I'm stumped at how to do this.
I've been looking at the `BreakIterator` which seems useful, but it doesn't really help me get the statement I need.

These are the cases I need to be supported:
The cursor is positioned at |

1. `SELECT * FROM something;|`  Cursor placed after the semicolon
2. `SELECT * FROM so|mething;`  Cursor placed within the statement
3. `SELECT * FROM something\nLEFT |JOIN foo USING (bar);` statement spanning several lines, again with the cursor placed both after the semicolon, or within the statement.

Any ideas for a simple solution for this?

Comment: Are you using an applet or some texteditor for accepting user input

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565836/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-jtextarea

this link lets you know the cursor position and you can get the next query snippet from this point,

Comment: No, I'm writing into a modified JTextArea. I can get the cursor position using getCaretPosition(), but I'm unsure of how I would cover all the cases I mentioned in a clean manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
// assuming the editorText is the contents of the edit window
String[] statements = editorText.split(";");

int statementCharactersProcessed = 0;

// assuming caret is at position caretIndex

int statementIndex = 0;
String statement;
while (caretIndex>statementCharactersProcessed+1) {
    // re-add the missing ;
    statement = statements[statementIndex++] + ";";
    statementCharactersProcessed += statement.length;
}

// statement should now be the value you're looking for
```

Comment: Perfect! Only thing lacking was a `.trim()` on the statement at the end.

Comment: There may be some other wrinkles in this algorithm as well... it's not a bad start, though!

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic that you want is running the all the statements inside the scope of cursor.

By "the scope of cursor" I mean: All between the previous semicolon till the next semicolon, from the start of line where cursor location (so if the cursor is after the semicolon - go to the start of the line and apply this logic)

Comment: That is indeed what I want, but also the corner case where the cursor is behind the last semicolon. This would actually be a very common case, as you write the statement, you finish up the the semicolon, so the caret would now be behind it.

Comment: yep , I update the answer - did it answer the question ?

Comment: Close. Only trouble is the third case, with multiline statements, but since the same logic applies, I'll accept your answer.
I was hoping there were a simpler way than to scan my way back and forth from the cursor, but oh well.
I will see if I can't use `indexOf()` to find my positions.

Answer (score 0):

i dnt know to implement it but i can suggest you if you can check for semicolon before and after the Cursor position. and execute the statement that falls between these semicolon should help you i feel.

:)